# Is the tag <MtouchSdkVersion> still necessary in Xamarin Applications?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

We have a 4 year old MonoTouch application, now a Xamarin.iOS application. It has a tag in each project

```
 <MtouchSdkVersion>3.0</MtouchSdkVersion>
```

In the list of warnings with the current Xamarin.iOS and Xcode 6.1.1, I see

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets: Warning: The iOS SDK version '3.0' is not installed. Using newer version '8.1' instead'. ({*myProjectName*})

I could manually update this tag or remove it. I do not see in the Xamarin Studio where to configure this on each project. Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should map to the **Project options**, **Build**, **iOS Build**, **General**, **SDK version** combobox.

If not found it could show you *Default* (not sure about the logic) but, beside **Default** it will only let you select the SDK that the presently configured Xcode provides (e.g. for Xcode 6.1 would see `8.1` for device builds).

note: it's possible it was left over to that value during the project's conversion to unified (which implies switching to `msbuild`).

Comment: I removed the tags from all the other .csproj files. It looks like that option is only available on the Main project and not on library DLL projects within the solution. It seems to run just fine. Thanks!